# Either distort or denounce

Tags: usage

In the following sentence which of the two words would be more idiomatic to say either **distort** or **denounce**

> It is unreasonable to ______ the statement of a man simply because he does not agree to your opinions

Answer (score 1):

Distort and denounce mean completely different things.  If you mean "change the meaning" say "distort".  If you mean "declare to be evil" say "denounce".

Comment: which one should be used according to you?

Comment: Suppose I have this question: "I own a _____ named Blackie"  Which of the following two words is more idiomatic, either **dog** or **cat**?

Comment: You can't answer because "dog" and "cat" mean have different meanings, but both are possible.  You can't answer your question because both "distort" and "denounce" are possible.  The answer depends on what you what to say.

Answer (score 0):

I think "denounce" is the better word. It is **never** reasonable to distort another person's statement.